# Filemaker conditional dropdown population

Tags: filemaker

continuing a project I have posted a few questions for already are you able to have a more precise definition of what a dropdown is populated with?

I am using FM Starting Point and have a Projects, Estimate and Task table. A project can hold multiple estimates and tasks. Estimates contain multiple lines (stored in a separate table).

When In a Project you can add a task for that project. What I want to do is replace the field that gives the task a name with a list of lines contained within the estimates related to the project i have selected to add the task from.

I have created a dropdown and using the inspector got it to display all estimate lines but somehow I need to write a function that will only select lines from estimates that are within the project and also only estimates that have a field set to "active" for example.

what I am struggling with is where I can programme such a thing? In the inspector, you are limited to displaying a value and cant programme in a statement. I have tried a script that executes OnObjectEnter or OnObjectModify but that doesn't appear to work.

Any ideas where I can enter a more complex set of rules as to what populates a dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Create a relationship with the criteria you need. Base the value list for the dropdown on this relationship.

As for display, The value list's second field can be from a calculated field with any data or several other fields stringed together if no single field is sufficient. The first field should be the ID.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to work on this over the past week. I have made relationships and stuff but I still can't find where I can insert some kind of if statement to narrow down irrelevant data

Comment: No if statements are requred. Just a relationship with the desired criteria. This video should help you out. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C62NlAR8vY